# Same grub menu for two GNU/Linux distributions

Tags: partition, grub2, dual-boot

I have Xubuntu 14.04 and BunsenLabs installed on my PC along with Windows 10.I installed Xubuntu the last so it installed grub onto the MBR.I then set it up to have Xubuntu as the default boot option and boot the last saved option, if any, to use `grub-reboot` to reboot the system remotely on a different OS.

This works fine from Xubuntu, but issuing the command from BunsenLabs and rebooting always shows Xubuntu as the default menu entry.

Is there some way to "share" the grub settings between the 2 partitions, or have them in a separate one so it works properly in both?

Comment: Automatically, no,  This is a fundamental design flaw with GRUB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific purpose of using `grub-reboot`, I found out that I can mount the Xubuntu partition from BunsenLabs and do `grub-reboot --boot-directory=/media/.../boot ENTRY` and it works.